# Parsing CSV values into a map with PHP

Tags: php, arrays, dictionary, key

If my text file is

```
Jack Jones;batter;100;
Bobby Brown;bowler;90;
```

I know how to get them into an array but how would I get them into an array with Keys?  For example, after I read the text file my array would be -

```
$player1 = ('name' => 'Jack Jones', 'skill' => 'batter', 'points' => '100');
$player2 = ('name' => 'Bobby Brown', 'skill' => 'bowler', 'points' => '90');

// therefore -
echo $player1['name'];  #This would output the name 'Jack Jones'
```

Comment: what does this have to do with mysql?

Comment: This is an awkward structure. Why not `$players = array( 0 => array('name' => 'Jack Jones', ...), 1 => array('name' => 'Bobby Brown' ...));`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can't directly as there's no information about column names in the text file. but if you know how to get this:

```
$player = (0 => 'Jack Jones', 1 => 'batter', 2 => '100');
```

and the column names are fixed, you could set up a second array containing the keys:

```
$column_names = array('name','skill','points');
```

and then use [array_combine](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php) to get your desired result:

```
$player = array_combine($column_names, $player);
echo $player['name'];  // 'Jack Jones'
```

Answer (score 1):

How do you parse your CSV file?
Do you use the Class CsvReader ?

In this case you can do something like:

```
Class CsvManager
{

function __construct()
{
$this->reader = new CsvReader();
$this->reader->SetCsvEncoding('yourEncoding');
$this->reader->SetDelimiter(';');
}

function Run($inString)
{
$this->reader->ParseCsv($inString,array(&$this, 'CsvCallback'), NULL);
}

function CsvCallback($inCsvArray)
{
$newArray = array();
$newArray['name'] = $inCsvArray[0];
$newArray['skill'] = $inCsvArray[1];
$newArray['points'] = $inCsvArray[2];
}

$file = pathToYourCsvFile.csv
$manager = new CsvManager();
$manager->Run($file);
```

hope this helps.